# Ununtu 19.04 unable to login error "usr/lib/paython3.7/email/_pycache_':permission denied"

Tags: boot, error-handling

Boots well but when I try to login errors appear

```
Error found while loading etc/profile 
usr/lib/paython3.7/email/_pycache_':permission denied
usr/lib/paython3.7/email/mime/_pycache_':permission denied
usr/lib/paython3.7/urllib/_pycache_':permission denied
usr/lib/paython3.7/http/_pycache_':permission denied
usr/lib/paython3.7/json/_pycache_':permission denied
usr/lib/paython3.7/xml/_pycache_':permission denied
usr/lib/paython3.7/xml/parser/_pycache_':permission denied
usr/lib/paython3.7/xmldom/_pycache_':permission denied
```

I tried installing pip3, successfully installed but to no vail
I did `autoremove` that is when this problem appeared.
 
I am fairly new to Ubuntu please explain solution in simple English

Thank you!

Comment: [Bug-Report][1]


  [1]: https://answers.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+question/681522

Comment: `find /usr/lib/paython3.7/  -iname '*pycache*' | xargs ls -al`